# How to find Country name from city name in Java?

Tags: java, android, twitter

I want to fetch Twitter user's country name.

For that I got the location from the `<location>` tag in which some users wrote their country's name, some wrote their city's name and some also wrote their state's name.

I want to get the country name for all users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to use the Google Maps API (though it might be overkill). For example, suppose someone has listed their country as "Jakarta" (actually a city in Indonesia). Then you would submit the following Maps API request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Jakarta&sensor=false

which returns a JSON object. You then parse that with your favorite JSON parser, and extract the "long_name" field of the "address components" field, with the type "country". In this case, that is "Indonesia".

Comment: Maybe this is stating the obvious, but you should keep a list of recognized country names (and common misspellings) so that you only do a Maps API request when you don't already recognize the country.

Comment: Keep in mind, that there are some [usage limits](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits), like you *have to* display the results on a (google) map ... ;)

Comment: That's interesting - I didn't realise that you had to display the results on a map. Of course, he's not actually using the geocodes, just using it as a very fancy lookup table. Having thought about it for a second, although this is a `quick and dirty' way to get results, it's obviously not the correct solution. A better way would be to build your own lookup table (perhaps using the Maps API to populate it...)

Answer (score 5):

Try to find an resource file or database with a convenient license (like [GeoWorldMap from here](http://www.geobytes.com/FreeServices.htm)). You won't get accurate infos from twitter users anyway, and what they write in their profile might be plain wrong. So I'd use a static resource and decode as many locations as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google Maps' autocomplete script to get possible countries for a city. It works like this: When you type "New York", it suggests you "New York, USA". But remember, you can't always get the country name from city name: There is a Berlin in Germany and in Connecticut, too.

Answer (score 4):

You could use geo tables in YQL:
[http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22jakarta%22](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22jakarta%22)

Example query: `select * from geo.places where text="jakarta"`